# smooth camera and tile scrolling c++

Tags: c++, sdl

> I have `50` pixel offset on my camera. The screen size is 640x480, and camera with offset is then 690x530; tile is 16x16 pixel.
>   Where `x`, `y` is screen's pixel position, 
>   `terrain` is an array of tiles, 
>   `startTileXinCamera` is tile on the most left in x axis on camera,
>   `startTileYinCamera` is tile on the most left in y axis on camera,
>   `tileXinCamera` is tile count that covered by camera in x axis,
>   `tileYinCamera` is tile count that covered by camera in y axis,
>   `tileCountX` is total tile count on x axis, not on screen but total for the terrain.

I'm having a trouble about camera and tile scrolling in 2D environment. So, basically I want to scroll my tiles smoothly per pixel, but instead it scrolls per tile and it looks "laggy" or stuttering.

Here is my tile rendering code:

```
void Terrain::render(SDL_Renderer* renderer, Camera* camera)
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int startTileXinCamera = camera->getCamera()->x / tileWidth;
    int startTileYinCamera = camera->getCamera()->y / tileHeight;
    int tileXinCamera = camera->cameraSizeToPositionX() / tileWidth;
    int tileYinCamera = camera->cameraSizeToPositionY() / tileHeight;

    for (int i = startTileYinCamera; i < tileYinCamera; i++)
    {
        for (int j = startTileXinCamera; j < tileXinCamera; j++)
        {
            terrainGraphic->render(renderer, x, y, tileClip[terrain[i * tileCountX + j]->type]);
            if (x < camera->getCamera()->w)
                x += tileWidth;
        }
        x = 0;
        if (y < camera->getCamera()->h)
            y += tileHeight;
    }
}
```

### Question:

How can I scroll my tiles smoothly per pixel and eliminate the unwanted effects?

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, you may want to post at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Inisheer thank you i'll try.

Comment: Try to use float instead of int

Comment: i've tried, it's still the same.

Comment: C++ does not have cameras or know about pixels. I've added the SDL tag because this code seems to be using the SDL library.

Comment: yes, it's using SDL. sorry forgot to mention it.

Comment: It is not the obvious `x += tileWidth;`, right?

Comment: x += tileWidth; is for placing the tile next to the other. so if my first tile is on 0,0 the next tile will be x += 16 or 16,0.

Comment: @nwp thank you. you made me realize the mistake, yes the problem was x and y with tile size addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I'm using predefined x,y coordinate int x = 0, y = 0; and x += tileWidth; to place the tile, instead of actually using the tile's coordinate. The tile's coordinate is then calculated by extracting it to the camera position, so it rendered correctly according to screen coordinate. I hope it's not confusing. Here is the code just in case it might be useful to someone out there. Sorry the code is ugly.

```
void Terrain::render(SDL_Renderer* renderer, Camera* camera)
{
    int startTileXinCamera = camera->getCamera()->x / tileWidth;
    int startTileYinCamera = camera->getCamera()->y / tileHeight;
    int tileXinCamera = camera->cameraSizeToPositionX() / tileWidth;
    int tileYinCamera = camera->cameraSizeToPositionY() / tileHeight;

    for (int i = startTileYinCamera; i < tileYinCamera; i++)
    {
        for (int j = startTileXinCamera; j < tileXinCamera; j++)
        {
            terrainGraphic->render(renderer, 
                terrain[i * tileCountX + j]->x - camera->getCamera()->x, 
                terrain[i * tileCountX + j]->y - camera->getCamera()->y, 
                tileClip[terrain[i * tileCountX + j]->type]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider rendering all of your tiles to a single texture and clipping that based on camera movement. instead of n x m tile sprites, you'll have 1 large one